# How to save power on a PC that is used for remote backups

Tags: backup, power, remote

I want to set up a NUC style PC to act as a recipient for backups when I travel. I will have it on a UPS and two large backup drives attached, but no monitor or keyboard or anything else attached.

When receiving backups it should use as much power as it needs to accept the backups over the internet as fast as it can. When not active it should use as little power as possible, including spinning down the drives if possible, for the sake of greenness, the electric bill and keeping it running cooler. How can I set up for this?

I do have some lower power PCs (TV stick type) but they have only USB 2 and are therefore slower to access the backup drives.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Well Bot, I think this asks exactly what I want to ask. I suppose the last paragraph is related but not totally necessary.  Shall I remove it?

Comment: Equip the machine with SSD drives.  I have a Windows 11 Desktop (no hard drives) and when it is idle (not suspended) and the monitor goes black, it draws 10 watts.  That is quite small power consumption.

Comment: The C: drive is SSD. The external drives are 2 x 8 TB Seagate Expansion Drives. There are no other drives.

Comment: The PC is quite warm to the touch and the processors cores are about 75C which is why I think it could be more efficient.